# Calculate the average reputation by user in SO

Tags: support, reputation, statistics

I'm just wondering how to calculate or to get a raw number of the average reputation per user in Stack Overflow or any other Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`select avg(reputation) from users`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/185654) returns 130 in 77ms on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), for Stack Overflow.

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer lets you write some pretty complicated queries, too, and if you `select` certain patterns of column data types, the thing can  render your data as a chart - that can really help you dissect how your favorite beta site is doing, if you're also active in other Stack Exchange communities. And queries can be executed on any site's data, so it's easy to compare two sites' results.

Like, the [distribution of avid users by reputation tier](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/160371/distribution-of-avid-users-by-reputation-tier#resultSets), or a [voting and user activity history graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph#graph), or your (or someone else's) [reputation history](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164480/reputation-races#graph), or whatever else comes to your mind!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 6):

You could probably get this information from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). There's a tutorial on how to use it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/help). I think you can find just about anything you want if you know how to ask it the right question :)

Comment: thanks men I'm looking at it now